# Compute pipeline as parent

Tags: vulkan

When reading docs for `VkPipelineCreateFlagBits`:

> VK_PIPELINE_CREATE_ALLOW_DERIVATIVES_BIT specifies that the pipeline to be created is allowed to be the parent of a pipeline that will be created in a subsequent call to vkCreateGraphicsPipelines

I am wondering why it explicitly states graphic pipelines. Why is the same not true for `vkCreateComputePipelines`? Seems like I can *ComputePipe -> GraphicsPipe* but not *ComputePipe -> ComputePipe* or *GraphicsPipe -> ComputePipe*!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the documentation. Compute pipelines do support derivatives too, and you can pass the base pipeline to derive from via the `basePipelineHandle` or `basePipelineIndex` of the `VkComputePipelineCreateInfo`.

I've been doing this in an example application and it worked fine. No validation errors and pipeline creation worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

That is probably a spec bug.
You can derive *GraphicsPipe* from *GraphicsPipe*.
And you can derive *ComputePipe* from *ComputePipe*.

(If in doubt, read the **Valid Usage** statements instead. Still, both texts are normative, so you should be nice and report things like this on [Vulkan spec GitHub](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues).)

Comment: It should be noted that [a bug has been filed for this, and Khronos has acknowledged that this is a documentation problem](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/525). Compute pipeliens are intended to be derived.